# TypeError: plugin is undefined datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatable, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using [jquery-datatables-rails](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-datatables-rails/3.4.0) vs 3.4 . previously I upgraded it from `'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 2.1.10.0.3'` . and just after the upgrading without changing anything else it stopped working . so i'm assuming that files placementment in `application.coffee.js` is fine and something is wrong with old datatable methods . But according to [Documentation](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10) old methods should also work . error in console on loading is only

> TypeError: plugin is undefined datatable jquery

Comment: you restart the server?

Comment: @inye yes , many times

Comment: you read de [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#220)?

Comment: @inye i read it but could not understand the relation with my bug

Comment: I do not read all and aso do not search, only read `it is incompatible with 2.10.0.3, because...`

Comment: which means error should not be there after upgrading right ? @inye